# Thrift transport in javascript client

Tags: javascript, thrift

I'm trying to build a javascript client for my Thrift server. The server is up and running and I can get calls to the server working with a PHP client. I just can't figure out the javascript client.

In particular, instantiating the transport baffles me. The tutorial at http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/js/ shows:

```
function calc() {
    var transport = new Thrift.Transport("/thrift/service/tutorial/");
    var protocol  = new Thrift.Protocol(transport);
    var client    = new CalculatorClient(protocol);
```

When I do this, I get an http 404 on "/var/www/thrift/service/tutorial/"

I've found one or two other examples that use

```
var transport = new Thrift.Transport("/service");
```

But that gives me a 404 as well.

I've never seen an explanation of what I'm supposed to pass to the constructor of Transport in javascript. In my PHP code, I create a socket and then pass that to the constructor of the Transport. However, javascript complains that Thrift.Socket() isn't a constructor.

The tutorial at http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/js/ isn't terribly helpful. It says:

> The first thing for using the Thrift files is setting up your
>   Transport protocol. At this time, it only supports AJAX and is as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> var transport = new Thrift.Transport("/thrift/service/tutorial/");
> ```

There's no description of what that path passed to the constructor should be.

I'm lost on this. What do I pass to the Transport constructor in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

To use a Javascript client you need a HTTP Thrift server (e.g. the one pointed out by yiding). You also need to use `TJSONProtocol`.

The files how to make a Thrift Java server work with an Thrift Javascript client are scattered throughout the source. I puzzled them together here: https://github.com/LukeOwncloud/ThriftJavaJavascriptDemo

Answer (score 1):

The argument is a URL to a website endpoint that acts as a thrift server using the HTTP processor and JSON protocol. The source code contains a [java test server example](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=thrift.git;a=blob;f=lib/js/test/src/test/Httpd.java;h=f1291d8018c92cffe2065ec28504d46518abc244;hb=HEAD) which can work with such a client.

For your own server, it should be able to act as a webserver, and handle things like CORS for cross-domain requests from your js client.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer yiding gave you has identified the problem.  I don't have a complete answer, but can give you a few links that may help you get things figured out.  If you're writing your server in PHP, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871858/is-it-possible-to-use-apache-thrift-on-a-regular-web-server) may help.  If you're writing your server in Java, [this blog post](http://moradanen.sopovs.com/2012/07/thrift-exposed-via-webapp-servlet.html) which links to [this sample code](https://github.com/isopov/thrift-test) may help.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers have already given enough clarity.

However to make things a bit more clear, assuming that your server is `localhost` and its running on port `8080`.

Let your project name be `Tutorial_service` and endpoint in your server project be `teach_thrift`
then you have to pass URL as below

```
var transport = new Thrift.Transport("http://localhost:8080/Tutorial_service/teach_thrift");
```

It should keep you going.. :)